# visual studio team suite : How to web test programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, testing, visual-studio-2005, web-testing

Good day,

I'm new to Visual Studio 2005 Team Suite web testing. Here's the action i'm trying to achieve.

On a webpage, I have a dropdownlist that is populated from a simple database table. In my tests, I want to click on each items of the dynamically populated dropdownlist, and after the postback, check if a label is visible on the page, which depends of the selected item in the dropdownlist.

However, since the dropdownlist is dynamically generated, I cannot simply 'record' and manually click on each item of the dropdownlist, so I have to code the test.

I'm pretty sure this is really simple to achieve, so I was wondering if there is a good free tutorial on web testing that I could use.

Thank you very much!

Comment: We cannot use any testing tool other than the ones provided in VS 2005 team suite.

Comment: VS2005 test tool actually is pretty buggy, can you use vs2008 version instead?

Comment: Unfortunalely, we cannot use VS2008 yet.

Answer (score 2):

You question.

> However, since the dropdownlist is
>   dynamically generated, I cannot simply
>   'record' and manually click on each
>   item of the dropdownlist, so I have to
>   code the test.

It seems to me that you need add "Data Binding" to your test.

Please read through this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243142(VS.80).aspx).

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

As long as it is fairly standard web-form postbacks you can use NUnitAsp:

http://nunitasp.sourceforge.net/

Here is a decent article on it here:
[ServerSide NUnitASP](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=TestingASP)

NUnitAsp is no longer really active or supported, but it still works good enough for simple form testing.

Comment: It seems not be supported and developed anymore : 
http://nunitasp.sourceforge.net/